# Deployed strapi on heroku server unable to add content

Tags: node.js, reactjs, content-management-system, strapi

I have used postgres as database on heroku server when im trying to use content types builder or trying to add collection it says in to auto reload as strapi develop but i dono how to do it server after deployment

Answer (score 4):

When Strapi is deployed on heroku, it is run with production flag - and adding collection is disabled.

The workflow should be

- Run strapi on local server

  npm run develop
- Create Content Types using Builder
- Add newly created files and Commit change in local git repository
- Push changes to heroku using this command.

  git push -u heroku master

You should see your collections on heroku.